Why does my CR-10 SE bed heat up to 60 °C just to cool down to 50 °C using Creality Print?
I just got a new CR-10 SE. I downloaded the newest version of Creality's slicer (It's called "Creality Print" instead of "Creality Slicer"; see pic at end), and printed a couple of test prints. The prints look great, but I noticed that every time I go to print something, the bed heats up to 60 °C during prep, then the printer waits for it to cool back down to 50 °C before actually printing. I have looked over all the settings in the slicer and cannot figure out why it does this. All the temperature settings (that I could find) are shown in the picture (which has them all set to 50 °C):

I even scoured through the G-code and found a couple of commands:
M140 S50 ;Set final bed temp
and
M190 S50 ;Wait for bed temp to stabilize
This should mean that the bed only ever heats up to 50 °C right?
Is this behavior because of a setting on the physical printer itself? Is it because I'm using Creality Cloud Print? Is it a bug in the newest version of their software?
I'm genuinely so lost as to where to look to change this.
The slicer that I downloaded is the highlighted one:


I have a CR10, but it's the 1st one. When I print I might manually tell the printer to preheat while I pick out what to print. On my CR10, that's choosing between PLA and ABS. Which are generally set to different temperatures then what I have the slicer set for. Are you doing the same? Or are you turning your printer on then running the GCode right away?

Do you have changed the bed PID settings, is it an overshoot or is it a stable 60 going to a stable 50? If you had OctoPrint we'd see the graphical image of the heating. Could you make a video and post a link to it?


I am not manually preheating my printer, I am just clicking print, and it preheats on its own.
It seems to be going to a stable 60 while it does the auto levelling, then has to wait to fall back down to 50 before actually printing


Did this always do this? Has it recently changed (new firmware? are you now using 50 instead of using to use 60 °C for the bed?). If heating prior to leveling occurs this might be related to the firmware setting PREHEAT_BEFORE_LEVELING, if enabled, the parameters set in the config file determine the warmup of the bed and the hotend. Please provide extra info if possible, e.g. does changing to the new slicer alone changed this, or did you change slicer settigns.

My guess would be that it's part of the autolevelling routine.
There's no reason to run autolevel on every print.  It's quite possible that routine heats the bed to 60 to ensure thermal expansion doesn't mess anything up.   Find the Preference item that is making autolevel part of every gcode, and uncheck it or the equivalent.
